# Swift SpriteKit Add timer to GameScene

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit, sprite

I have looked around at many articles, but none of them seem to make sense or are relevant to my issue. I want to give the user a set time to press a node. If they succeed in pressing the node within the set time the timer should reset, if they fail to press the node within the set time it will be game over.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        if square.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
            moveSquare()
            GameScene.score+=1
            scoreLabel.text = "\(GameScene.score)"
            }
        } else {
            gameOverScene()
        }
}
```

so my question is how do I set the timer up to achieve those requirements, and where do I put the code?

Answer (score 2):

Use SKActions instead of timers:

```
let countdown = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5),
                                   SKAction.perform(#selector(gameOver), onTarget: Self)])
run(countdown, withKey: "gameOverTimer")
```

(this assumes that the function `gameOver` is the one you want to call if the correct button is not touched in time)

and in `touchesBegan`, if the correct node is touched:

```
removeAction(forKey: "gameOverTimer")
```

Comment: I *think* this is correct, but I've written it from memory. I'll try and test it and correct any errors.

Comment: @selector is no longer used, it is #selector now